# facebook not showing my images in posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have this webpage that I want to post to my profile in FB.  FB absolutely does not see images on my page.  I want it to show one image in particular.  I have used FB Lint debugging and have all my meta og tags filled out. The Lint tool sees everything, EXCEPT the image (it's got its outline, it shows the path, if you click on it, it takes you to the image).  Just. No. Image. [Here are my scraped url results](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http://www.floozysauce.com/floozy_meatballs.html).  And [here is my graph API](http://graph.facebook.com/10150542862909287).  For reference, [here is the page I want to post a link to](http://www.floozysauce.com/floozy_meatballs.html).  My image is 1.5:1 ratio, the file size is under 100k, it is 720x480, I have stored it in the root folder with the web page.  I dont' know what else to do.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what if you remove the `og:image:type` tag? I've never had to use that and it's the only thing that stands out to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the image link you specified.  However, when going to it, I get a 403 error.  Fix that error and then facebook will be able to display it.
http://floozysauce.com/FloozyMeatballs-small.jpg

Comment: I don't get that error, and I have viewed this page/image in different browsers, different computers and different locations.  Hmm, the permissions on it show 644.  Is this correct for file viewing?

Comment: I still get a 403, you should ask your webmaster (or server admin) for assistance in allowing that file to be served with a 200.

Comment: *UPDATE*  I changed the file permissions on this file to 755, I even tried changing the permissions for the entire website to 777 (very briefly!) but the image still doesn't show up in Facebook's debugger.

Comment: Still getting a 403.  I'm a programmer, not a server admin. Sorry.

Comment: I went into my .htaccess file and started removing rules, even going so far as to remove everything and upload a blank file, and still the facebook debugger sees no image.  When you visit the webpage (not the link to the image) are you seeing the image or getting an error?

Comment: I had to contact tech support for my hosting company; there was software blocking image access to places like Facebook.  Thank you for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

I know the questions was asked a while ago, but just to post an alternative for those with the same problem.
I had the same problem tried changing de 644 permission to 755, but that didnt work, so I got it back to 644. Finally I found that my .htacess file was blocking these kind of files to be served in other sites (such as facebook) so i just removed it and then it worked.